# Can I identify the sub class from a base class parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Take a look at the following. The question near the end of the code - in the "whoAmI" function...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MY_TEST_PROJECT
{
    // a form class
    public partial class frmTestForm1 : Form
    {
        // zillion lines of code

        private void aFunction()
        {        
            ClassTest.whoAmI(this);
        }

        // zillion lines of code
    }

    // another form class...
    public partial class frmTestForm2 : Form
    {
        // zillion lines of code

        private void aFunction()
        {        
            ClassTest.whoAmI(this);
        }

        // zillion lines of code
    }

    // a home made test class
    public static class ClassTest
    {
        // zillion lines of code

        public static void whoAmI(Form theForm)
        {
            // IS THERE A WAY TO SEE WHAT KIND OF FORM theForm IS?

            // LIKE:
            // if (theForm IS A frmTestForm1)
            //   doThis();
            // else if (theForm IS A frmTestForm2)
            //   doThat();
        }

        // zillion lines of code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with the keyword [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx).

Also, you might want to solve your problem using [polymorphism](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html) instead of checking the type.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways you can do this:

- as you have guessed you can use "is" key word as Sjoerd has proposed

> ```
> if (theForm is frmTestForm1)
>    doThis();
> ```

```
//So on
```

- Another approach is to use reflection to get the exact type of the form you have. Your code should look like somthing like this:

> if (theForm.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType
>   == typeof(frmTestForm1))
>     doThis();

The drawback of the first approach is that if, for example, your frmTestForm2 is derivative of frmTestForm1 and you use code like this `if(yourform is frmTestForm1)` and your form is pointing to a frmTestForm2 instance "is" keyword will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this and it is not working? There is no problem trying to get a type from an object. Although you are sending it in as the base type the object still is a derived class type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (theForm.GetType().ToString() == typeof(frmTestForm1).ToString())
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `UnderlyingSystemType`, which Koynov uses. I now prefer his answer.